# Meaning of 「X 一緒なら Y 一緒」

Tags: grammar, meaning, syntax

> その高校とは昔から仲が悪くて学力のレベルも一緒なら評判や人気までも一緒

More context: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj333.jpg

Is 「X 一緒なら Y 一緒」 a common structure? What is its meaning?

My attempt: "Relations with that high school have always been bad. From  scholastic ability to reputation and popularity."

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A + も + B + なら/ば + X + も + Y + だ` is a pattern used to present two similar facts in parallel. Here are relevant articles:

- JGram: [も～ば～も](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=mo-ba-mo)
- jtest4you: [Learn JLPT N2 Grammar: も～ば～も (mo~ba~mo)](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%82%82%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%B0%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%82-mobamo/)

In your example sentence, the "B" and "Y" parts happen to be the same na-adjective, `同じ`. The speaker is saying two facts in parallel, "academic abilities (of the two schools) are the same" and "reputation and popularity (of the two schools) are the same".

なら is not always translated as "if". It can work as something like an emphatic topic marker, similar to English "speaking of ～" or "regarding ～". Here's the dictionary entry which is (probably) relevant:

> [なら](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/165205/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89/)
>
> - ［副助］《断定の助動詞「なり」の未然形から》体言に付く。話題となるものを取り上げて示す。…について言えば。「母―間もなく帰ると思います」
> - ［並助］《近世語》いくつかの事柄を並列して言うのに用いる。…といい、…といい。→なり［並助］

Typical idiomatic usage of this kind of なら is found in this question: [Meaning of pattern 「XがXなら、YもYだ」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/870/5010)

Answer (score 3):

The structure is 「X **も**一緒なら Y **も**一緒」.

I think the meaning of this structure is similar to "not only ... but also" or "as well as".

Not only scholastic ability but also reputation and popularity is same between this high school and that high school.