# Is there an english expression equivalent to 「先祖も酷ければ子孫も子孫」?

Tags: expressions

It should mean something like "If the ancestors are cruel, so would their offsprings" right?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/870/5010 and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40426/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, if you're asking about English, wouldn't the English language SE be more appropriate?

「酷い」　here  does not mean "cruel", but more like "terrible" or "awful".

The closest English equivalent I can think of would be:

> Like father, like son.

Though note that the English can have either a good meaning or a bad meaning, unlike the phrase you posted.

That aside, the phrase you have posted is rather uncommon.  The idiom used in Japanese is:

> 蛙｛かえる｝の子｛こ｝は蛙｛かえる｝

Note that this phrase is used in a negative way only.

Comment: "the apple doesn't fall far from the tree"

Comment: Thank you. English isn't my mother language so I forget these simple things... And to A.Ellett, that's good as well, but it doesn't fit for me, thanks

Comment: @A.Ellett Ah, that's another good one!