# Meaning of 大概 in「ボクも大概だ」?

Tags: meaning, words

The first character starts by saying their view on a situation, the second then replies with an opinion that is viewed as ridiculous and unbelievable by the first. This first character then replies:

> ボクも大概だけどキミも相当だな

In the subtitles this is translated as:

> I have issues, but you're just as bad.

While I understand the translation for the second half, 「ボクも大概だ」 doesn't seem to make sense.「大概」 meaning 'generally' or 'mostly', is it akin to the phrase 'I'm not all there' in English?

Comment: What was the sentence that came before this one? I wonder if this is `ボクも大概(問題がある)だけど` with the `問題がある` omitted.

Comment: 1: 前に言った「2人とも」...って キルアとゴンの事じゃ無くてキルアとキミのこと? 2: うんそうだよ and then 1 says the line in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries say the basic meaning of 大概 is something like "moderate", "overview", "almost all", "usually", etc.

> - 大概のところでやめる / 大概にする to stop before going too far; not to go to extremes
> - この店で大概の品物は見つかる。 Almost all items are found in this shop.
> - 土曜日は大概会社にいる。 I am usually at my office on Saturdays.

However `noun + も + 大概だ` means something different. It's a way of indirectly implying something/someone is equally out of the way, abnormal, extreme, bad, etc. Basically it's interchangeable with `noun + も + 相当だ`. I don't know if this usage is originally sarcasm or euphemism. For some reason we usually see も used with 大概 in this sense, so you can memorize this as a set phrase.

Examples:

> - 日本語は難しいといわれるが、英語も大概だと思う。
> - あの部長は怒ってばかりいますけど、部長も大概ですよ。

[大辞林 has the corresponding definition](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A4%A7%E6%A6%82-556507#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88):

> ④ふつうでないこと。はなはだしいこと。

To my surprise, デジタル大辞泉 [does not explain](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/132643/meaning/m0u/%E5%A4%A7%E6%A6%82/) this usage at least directly.

By the way, the sentence in question can be rephrased as ボクもボクだけどキミもキミだな. See: [Meaning of pattern 「XがXなら、YもYだ」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/870/5010)

Answer (score 1):

大概だ is a kind of idiomatic phrase; perhaps this 大概 is used in the sense of "mostly" or "to a great extent" and 大概だ is used usually in the sense of "being mostly/very bad," "shoddy" or "ordinary/dime-a-dozen." Anyway it has a different meaning from its literal definition and has a negative nuance.